# Deployment of Adonis JS Project on IIS8

Tags: node.js, iis-8, adonis.js

I have a project built on nodejs (adonisjs). I want it to deploy in IIS 8. What should I do? I have uploaded it under inetpub/wwwroot directory. I have my node, iisnode installed.My project is working fine when i try to run it by `adonis serve --dev` command. But when i try to access it from live server it shows error.
Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: Yeah I have @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol

Comment: Thank but I got already had working too

Comment: Thats great bro :) @ßiansorÅ.Ålmerol